# Accesing a file in a ftp server

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I have made a program, and there is a function where it gets a text file called news_2014.txt from a ftp server. I currently have this code:

```
def getnews():
server = 'my ftp server ip'
ftp= ftplib.FTP(server)
username = 'news2'
password = ' '
ftp.login(username,password)
filename = 'ftp://my ftp server ip/news/news_2014.txt'
path = 'news'
ftp.cwd(path)
ftp.retrlines('RETR' + filename, open(filename, "w").open)
```

I wanna make so the program displays the lines using readlines onto a Tkinter label. But if I try calling the top function, it says:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'ftp://news/news_2014.txt'
```

Comment: maybe try using the filename `news_2014.txt` instead of the full path?

Comment: Escape your backslashes

Comment: I want to read text from the news_2014.txt file. Is that the way to do it? the 'RETR'?

Comment: Use .strip() to remove unwanted white space  ?

Comment: @ Tharanga Abeyseela I mean that is ftp.retrlines('RETR' + filename, open(filename, "w").open) the correct way of getting a file to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RETR wants just the remote path name, not a URL. Similarly, you cannot `open` a URL; you need to pass it a valid local filename.

Changing it to `filename = 'news_2014.txt'` should fix this problem trivially.

The `retrlines` method retrieves the lines and optionally performs a callback. You have specified a callback to open a local file for writing, but that's hardly something you want to do for each retrieved line. Try this instead:

```
textlines = []
ftp.retrlines('RETR ' + filename, textlines.append)
```

then display the contents of `textlines`. (Notice the space between the `RETR` command and its argument, too.)

I would argue that the [example in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) is confusing for a newcomer. Someone should file a bug report.

Comment: How do I fix this? This is my first time using ftplib, so how do I get news_2014 and read it? What is the command?

Comment: I added a fix; please refresh.

Comment: It's not doing anything. Is the code downloading it or is it just viewing it?

Comment: It wasn't doing anything with the downloaded content. Sorry for missing that; see edit.

Comment: How to I make the downloaded data appear each line through a label? Also, cant I just use urllin.urlretrieve?

Comment: That usually means you have an invalid server name.